# Trouble with alignment on Android 2.1 using merge

Tags: android, layout

The main idea is that the FrameLayout (Black) is centered and the LinearLayout (Red) aligns at the bottom. This works perfectly on my 4.x emulators and on my Galaxy Nexus. Like this:

[image: Good Layout]

In Eclipse ADT the layout previews look fine on all sizes. However when running this on a 2.1 emulator the FrameLayout (Black) seems shifted downwards.

[image: BadLayout]

I got the following layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:background="#000000" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Anyone got any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Have you tried using a "regular" layout (e.g. a RelativeLayout) instead of `<merge>`?

Comment: I just tried replacing the merge with RelativeLayout. I could get the layout I want by setting (Black) layout_centerInParent and (Red) alignParentBottom. However, strangly enough this gives me the exact same problem. I suspect that android 2.1 is ignoring the 70dp margin I have at the bottom (of Black).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the 70dp-margin. gezdy's approach should work, in that case, since his LinearLayout "recognizes" the presence of the red bar and rearranges the black box to the "new" center accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:background="#000000" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         android:background="#FF0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me exactly what I wanted (as well as on 2.1).